# How to format date with value returned as variable in PHP

Tags: php, date

Im working on a WP site using WP Download Manager Pro. I am able to access the object's date like this:

```
<?php $packageID = get_field('user_submitted_app_download_id'); $post_date = $package['post_date'];?>
```

It is returning the date like this "2018-01-03 10:56:11" I need to re-arrange it so it posts like this "03-01-2018" -> m-d-Y

I keep getting errors and don't know what I'm doing wrong. From PHP.net -

`<?php $post_date = $package['post_date']; echo date_format($post_date, m-d-Y); ?>`

I get this laundry list of errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant m - assumed 'm' in
>   /home/ntecosys/sandboxwp2/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/includes/class-renderer.php(467)
>   : eval()'d code on line 18
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd' in
>   /home/ntecosys/sandboxwp2/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/includes/class-renderer.php(467)
>   : eval()'d code on line 18
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' in
>   /home/ntecosys/sandboxwp2/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/includes/class-renderer.php(467)
>   : eval()'d code on line 18
>
> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,
>   string given in
>   /home/ntecosys/sandboxwp2/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/includes/class-renderer.php(467)
>   : eval()'d code on line 18

How do I reformat the date?

Comment: missing quotes on the format string http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Its always something simple! I added quotes but get the error in the answer below now.

Comment: error is clear, you are proving a string to a function expecting something else

Comment: I get that. I just don't know how to correct it.

Comment: i would suspect there is a WP way, i dont use WP so dont know it. while i could do it with pure php, if your going to use a framework, you should use its functions where they exist

Comment: Thank you, I'm always learning. Or at least trying to. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. I will look for the pure php way to do it.

Comment: you really should do it the WP way,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$post_date` is a string, and `date_format()` expects a DateTime Object.

This is the shorter way, converting your string to a unix timestamp:

```
echo date('m-d-Y' strtotime($post_date));
```

Otherwise you'll need to use [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse your string into an object that you can manipulate with `date_format`, but that's a lot more verbose.

Comment: Thank you, that put me on the right track. I modified the output slightly but this worked for me - <?php echo date_format(new DateTime($post_date), 'M j, Y');  ?>

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to wrap your date format in quote

```
echo date_format($post_date, 'm-d-Y');
```

Comment: I have added the single quotes, but get this error now: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in /home/ntecosys/sandboxwp2/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/includes/class-renderer.php(467) : eval()'d code on line 18

Comment: This is a different error, if the post_data is a string try creating a DateTime object from it, perhap use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php